# Vertically Align navigation on the center left

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to do a navigation title on the right of the screen and add an animation to it.
The top title worked perfectly but trying to rotate the title messes up the javascript.

The animation is: 1st

[image]

and transforms into

[image]

What I'm having trouble is placing the next title vertically in the middle on the left of the page like this

[image]

So far I'm at this stage and stuck:
[image]

Here's my code with the javascript:

```
<div class="navbarProjects">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class="spread">Projects</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="navbarAbout">
            <h1 class="spread">About</h1> 
        </div>
        <script>
            var spread = document.getElementsByClassName('spread');
                [].forEach.call(spread, function(el) {
                  // replace the content width divs
                  el.innerHTML = '<span>' + el.innerText.split('').join('</span><span>') + '</span>'
                  // custom :hover
                  el.onmouseenter = function(e) {
                    var childern = e.target.childNodes
                    var width = e.target.offsetWidth / childern.length 
                    for (var i = 0, child; child = childern[i]; i++) child.style.minWidth = width + 'px'
                  }
                  // remove custom style again
                  el.onmouseleave = function(e) {
                    var childern = e.target.childNodes
                    for (var i = 0, child; child = childern[i]; i++) child.style.minWidth = '0'
                  }
                })
        </script>
.navbarProjects {
    text-align: center;
    top: 2%;
    font-size: 32px;  
}

.navbarAbout {
    font-size: 32px;
    padding-top: 0;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}



.spread  {
    text-align:center;

}

.spread span {
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    text-align:center;
    min-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: what about adding `float: left;` on your `.navAbout` rule

Comment: tried that. it would compress the div to the size of the text only. which stops the javascript from working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the CSS I came up with to attempt to solve your issue:

I used classes found here: `http://spotlifefilms.com/`

See: https://jsfiddle.net/p8eqxpce/3/

```css
.navbarFounder, .navbarServices, .navbarProjects, .navbarAbout {
    position: fixed;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 70px;
}

.navbarFounder, .navbarServices {
    width: 100vh;
    top: 50%;
}
.navbarProjects, .navbarAbout {
    width: 100vw;
    right: 50%;
}

.navbarFounder {
    left: 0px;
    transform:
        rotate(270deg)
        translate(35px, calc(-50vh + 35px));
}
.navbarServices {
    right: 0px;
    transform:
        rotate(90deg)
        translate(-35px, calc(-50vh + 35px));
}
.navbarProjects {
    bottom: 0px;
    transform:
        rotate(180deg)
        translateX(-50vw);
}
.navbarAbout {
    right: 50%;
    transform:
        rotate(0deg)
        translateX(50vw);
}
```

Comment: I will note that transforms will probably not work as you expect in internet explorer.

Answer (score 1):

so, i've come up with a solution that will only work if your font-size remains constant (if it's variable you'll need to use javascript/jquery for this particular solution to work) but if you set the margin for the `about` element to `calc(100% - yourWidth);` you'll be able to get it to work. i've made a jsfiddle:

EDIT: updated jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/w7zfajea/4/

Comment: Thank you! I tried also moving it down to the center after your code and its spreads out of the page. Any idea how I can contain it or limit it to the edge? tried using width and height doesnt work

Comment: @MuaathAli see my edited jsfiddle, it's not the cleanest and probably not the best way either but it works. just play with the `max-width` and the `margin-left` values on the `.navbarAbout` rule in the css to adjust your positioning/height values

Comment: Thanks alot! Now just trying to figure out how to do another one on the right